# change the date format in a text box

Tags: excel, vba

A text box in a user form has the vba below in order to paste the date in column D on my worksheet. I need the format of the date to be pasted as follows: "YYYY/MM/DD" exactly in this order.

However at the moment the code below pastes the date "DD/MM/YYYY". Am i missing something? thanks

```
  .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.txtDate.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 4).NumberFormat = "YYYY/MM/DD"
```

Comment: `.Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Format(Me.txtDate.Value, "yyyy/mm/dd")` You can also set the format directly in the cell, though Format/Custom/YYYY/MM/DD.

Comment: @KostasK. number formats don't date-format strings that Excel doesn't recognize as dates.

Comment: @Mat's Mug You're right. Misread it altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A textbox contains a `String`. A date-formatted cell contains a `Date` (if you want Excel to understand it as a *date* anyway). You're missing a conversion.

```
Dim dateValue As Date
dateValue = ToDate(Me.txtDate.Value)

.Cells(lRow, 4).Value = dateValue
.Cells(lRow, 4).NumberFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
```

Where `ToDate` would be a function that takes a `String` and returns a `Date`. There are many ways to go about this, and you'll want to handle the situation where the provided string isn't a valid date.

Here's *one* way:

```
Private Function ToDate(ByVal value As String) As Date
    ToDate = DateValue(value) 'raises error 13 "type mismatch" if invalid
End Function
```

If that's good enough, and only needed in one place, then you could inline it:

```
.Cells(lRow, 4).Value = DateValue(Me.txtDate.Value)
.Cells(lRow, 4).NumberFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
```